# Copy first Row of Each Data after every empty Row

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to copy the first highlighted row of each new data after empty row and i have looked around to find a way which could do this but cannot find.

I can do this manually by putting name of rows to copy but code should be dynamic because rows order can be changed but there must be empty rows after new data.

Any help will be appreciated.

after copying and pasting the result would be like this.

[image]

My try

```
 Sub copynextfirstrow()
    
    lastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Copy
    
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Cells.PasteSpecial
    End Sub
```

Comment: There is no connection between your code and what you are asking for... Where do you want copying the lines in discussion? Do you want copying all these lines one below the other?

Comment: ... Yes i am unable to find how this thing can be done- `Do you want copying all these lines one below the other?` YES!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub copynextfirstrow()
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, i As Long, rngCopy As Range
    
    Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    lastRow = sh1.cells(sh1.rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh1.rows(i)) = 0 And WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh1.rows(i + 1)) > 0 Then
            If rngCopy Is Nothing Then
                Set rngCopy = sh1.rows(i + 1)
            Else
                Set rngCopy = Union(rngCopy, sh1.rows(i + 1))
            End If
        ElseIf i = 1 And WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh1.rows(i)) > 0 Then
             Set rngCopy = sh1.rows(i)
        End If

    If Not rngCopy Is Nothing Then 
          rngCopy.Copy
          sh2.Range("A1").cells.PasteSpecial
    End If
End Sub
```

It should be fast enough, firstly making a `Union` of the rows to be copied and pasting all the range at once.

I couldn't understand that an empty row is one having only a cell in A:A empty, so I created a piece of code which considers an empty row the one not having any record on all columns...

Comment: thank you very much for this favor  @FaneDuru This is exactly what I have been looking for.

Comment: @Mento: Glad I could help!

Comment: I just found one problem that when data starts from 1st row it does not include the first Row data @FaneDuru I tried to change these `(i + 1)` but code is already starting from 1st row then why its not including first row data.

Comment: @Mento: Not exactly "a problem",  I would say... It was  not mentioned in your question. I adapted the code to also copy the first row. Not tested, but it should work. Now I must leave my office...

Comment: Alright no problem i will use it, as it is thank you.

Comment: Yeah Thank you so much its working great.

Answer (score 1):

Quick example: search for blank cells and see if offset values exist:

```
Sub Blah()
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange, Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    For Each Cell In rng
        If Cell.Offset(1, 0) <> "" Then Debug.Print Cell.Offset(1, 0)
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you but its not pasting the data?

Comment: .UsedRange misses the first record in OP's example. @Tragamor
 love the .intersect usage though, stealing it.